# Charts and plots in .Net 4 using Windows Form

Tags: .net-4.0, charts, plot, zedgraph

I am using Windows Form and .Net 4 in Visual Studio 2010. I need to do some cross-plots, and would like to have a few features, as cursor and zoom in and out.

I tried to use ZedGraph, however I was not able to add its controller to the toolbox. I don't know if I have done something wrong or if it is not compatible.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll assume you are using WinForms (as opposed to WPF).

1. Add references to the ZedGraph DLLs to your project

   - Right-click references in the solution explorer and select Add Reference
   - Select the browse tab and locate `ZedGraph.dll` (also `ZedGraph.Web.dll` if needed)
2. Rebuild the project (F6)
3. In the Toolbox, check that `ZedGraphControl` has appeared under `Components`

This control can be added to the design layout of a form.

Alternatively, once you have the reference added, you can add a graph to a form in code with the following:

```
using ZedGraph;

ZedGraphControl myZedGraphControl = new ZedGraphControl();
// set size, location, etc. properties
form1.Controls.Add(myZedGraphControl);
```